# HTTP traffic thru redsocks service using iptables not working

Tags: networking, iptables

Am trying to redirect all my computer's traffic thru my local redsocks service on port 12345. And though https is working for some reason http doesnt appear to be.

/etc/redsocks.conf

```
base {
    log_debug = on;
    log_info = on;
    log = "file:/var/log/redsocks.log";

    daemon = on;

    redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {

    local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_port = 12345;

    ip = proxy.uclv.cu;
    port = 3128;

    type = http-connect;

    login = "MyUser";
    password = "MyPassword";
}
```

iptables configuration

```
iptables -t nat -N REDSOCKS

iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN

# Anything should be redirected to port 12345
iptables -t nat -A REDSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports 12345

# Any tcp connection should be redirected to REDSOCKS chain
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REDSOCKS
```

Executing command sudo iptables -v -x -n -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Executing command sudo iptables -t nat -nL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain REDSOCKS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8          
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            100.64.0.0/10       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.0.0/16      
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.16.0.0/12       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/16      
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            198.18.0.0/15       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/4         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            redir ports 12345
```

If I try a https site such as https://google.com it works. But if it is a site like http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ it doesn't.

However if i change http-connect to http-relay in the redsocks config file the opposite happens.

Is there any way i can make both http and https work at the same time?

Comment: well, for your test try a site that actually delivers http content. google will just switch to https.

Comment: @DougSmythies i have also tried the ubuntu repos directions which are http, and they don't work

Comment: Then please put that information in your question. Are you showing us all of your iptables rules? If not please do. Suggest `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and `sudo iptables -t nat -v -x -n -L`

Comment: @DougSmythies Additional information added

Comment: ??? Please to entire iptables rules sets, in the format I asked for.

Comment: @DougSmythies I added more info to the problem, can you please help with this?

Comment: REDIRECT only redirects locally, is REDSOCKS local on your system?

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using. Once I made a frontend for redsocks available in launchpad https://launchpad.net/~anandogc/+archive/ubuntu/proxywise. Maintained upto Ubuntu-16.04. Will try to update it in couple of days. You can give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redsocks2 website (https://github.com/semigodking/redsocks) probably explains your problem. This example must be contained in the configuration file. I quote verbatim:

"To make redsocks2 works with GoAgent proxy, you need to set proxy type as 'http-relay' for HTTP protocol and 'http-connect' for HTTPS protocol
respectively. Suppose your goagent local proxy is running at the same server as redsocks2, The configuration for forwarding connections to GoAgent is like below:

```
    redsocks {
     bind = "192.168.1.1:1081"; //HTTP should be redirect to this port.
     relay = "192.168.1.1:8080";
     type = http-relay; // Must be 'htt-relay' for HTTP traffic.
     autoproxy = 1; // I want autoproxy feature enabled on this section.
     // timeout is meaningful when 'autoproxy' is non-zero.
     // It specified timeout value when trying to connect to destination
     // directly. Default is 10 seconds. When it is set to 0, default
     // timeout value will be used.
     timeout = 13;
    }
    redsocks {
     bind = "192.168.1.1:1082"; //HTTPS should be redirect to this port.
     relay = "192.168.1.1:8080";
     type = http-connect; // Must be 'htt-connect' for HTTPS traffic.
     autoproxy = 1; // I want autoproxy feature enabled on this section.
     // timeout is meaningful when 'autoproxy' is non-zero.
     // It specified timeout value when trying to connect to destination
     // directly. Default is 10 seconds. When it is set to 0, default
     // timeout value will be used.
     timeout = 13;
     }
```

"

Comment: This is good, but i don't get why i need to use http-relay for the HTTP to work, why I need the timeout and the autoproxy features?

Comment: @jogarcia Maybe that was the reason why in some occasions you will only be allowed to HTTPS traffic, and in others only HTTP. You need both settings to get both traffics.
The autoproxy is for, for example, try direct connection before using the proxy. If this does not succeed in the seconds specified in the configuration, then passes to use the proxy.
The `autoproxy` is characteristic of **redsocks2** exclusively.

Comment: @jogarcia By the way, could you pass all the connections already?

Comment: You mean my working iptables and redsocks config?

Comment: I mean just that, because I have spent time trying and nothing. The truth is very necessary for me to work. If you did it and you know the settings already, it would be very useful for me.

Comment: I posted what worked for me as an answer, check it out

Answer (score 1):

I used transocks (https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks) instead of redsocks, my iptables config looks like that:

https://gist.github.com/andersondanilo/a28e7165fa8a9700d8ead20a224ecf44

example transocks config:

```
listen = "0.0.0.0:12345"

# Connect to HTTP Proxy
proxy_url = "http://USER:PASS@HOST:80"

# Connect to socks5 Proxy (you can create with ssh)
# proxy_url = "socks5://10.20.30.40:1080" 

[log]
level = "info"
```

script to configure iptables:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Transocks: https://github.com/cybozu-go/transocks
# 1. Install: go get -u github.com/cybozu-go/transocks/...
# Note: depending on your vension of go, you will need the env: GO111MODULE=on
# 2. Create a "transocks" user
# 3. Execute: sudo -u transocks $HOME/go/bin/transocks -f transocks.toml

set -e
stty -echoctl

# Point to the transparent socket port (running in an exclusive user)
TRANSOCKS_PORT=12345
TRANSOCKS_USER=transocks

# Redirect all the network of your computer (except transocks user)
REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK=1

# Redirect access point (wifi hotspot)
AP_SUBNET_ENABLED=1
AP_SUBNET_IFACE=ap0
AP_SUBNET_RANGE="192.168.12.0/24"

function action_up()
{
    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Adding iptables chain rules"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -t nat -N TRANSOCKS
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 0.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 100.64.0.0/10 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 198.18.0.0/15 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 224.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -d 240.0.0.0/4 -j RETURN
    iptables -v -t nat -A TRANSOCKS -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-ports $TRANSOCKS_PORT

    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting non-transocks user"
        echo "--------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "-----------------------"
        echo "# Redirecting AP subnet"
        echo "-----------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -I PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -I INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi
}

function action_down()
{
    if [ "$REDIRECT_LOCAL_NETWORK" = 1 ]; then
        echo "------------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning non-transocks rules"
        echo "------------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner ! --uid-owner $TRANSOCKS_USER -j TRANSOCKS
    fi

    if [ "$AP_SUBNET_ENABLED" = 1 ]; then
        echo "--------------------------"
        echo "# Cleaning AP subnet rules"
        echo "--------------------------"
        iptables -v -t nat -D PREROUTING -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -j TRANSOCKS
        iptables -v -D INPUT -i $AP_SUBNET_IFACE -s $AP_SUBNET_RANGE -p tcp -m tcp --dport $TRANSOCKS_PORT -j ACCEPT
    fi

    echo "-----------------------------"
    echo "# Cleaning and removing chain"
    echo "-----------------------------"
    iptables -v -F TRANSOCKS -t nat
    iptables -v -X TRANSOCKS -t nat
}

trap 'action_down' SIGINT

action_up

echo
echo "Hit Ctrl+C to remove the ip table rules"
echo


while :
do
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: That sounds very cool. But how do you install transocks, if you would elaborate on your answer that would be much better.

Comment: i added more info

Comment: Hi @AndersonDanilo , is there any way to fix tansocks package installation ? I have tried to install and receive some dependencies errors. Thanks.

Comment: I am not used to the go ecosystem, however, if there is some dependency conflict with your environment, i would suggest using another environment, like goenv (i never used it in go, only in other languages). Maybe you can use this other environment only to compile the binary.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the answer of Atreyu94 and some other examples this is what worked for me:

#### /etc/redsocks.conf

```
base {
    log_debug = on;
    log_info = on;
    log = "file:/var/log/redsocks.log";

    daemon = on;

    redirector = iptables;
}

redsocks {
    local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_port = 12345;

    ip = my.proxy.dns;
    port = 3128;

    type = http-connect;

    login = "myUser";
    password = "myPassword";
}

redsocks {
    local_ip = 0.0.0.0;
    local_port = 12346;

    ip = my.proxy.dns;
    port = 3128;

    type = http-relay;

    login = "myUser";
    password = "myPassword";
}
```

#### Executing command sudo iptables -t nat -nL

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDSOCKS   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain REDSOCKS (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/8           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            10.0.0.0/8          
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            100.64.0.0/10       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.0/8         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            169.254.0.0/16      
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.16.0.0/12       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.0.0/16      
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            198.18.0.0/15       
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            240.0.0.0/4         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 redir ports 12346
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443 redir ports 12345
REDIRECT   tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:11371 redir ports 12346
```

As you can see in my tables i redirect all HTTP traffic to the http-relay port i also redirect the tcp traffic of port 11371 thru the http-relay port i don't even know why that works but it does. That particular redirection i saw it in:

https://jmkhael.io/escape-proxy-hell-with-redsocks/

Also i only redirect OUTPUT traffic because am not working on a server but on my personal computer. If you want to use the computer you are working on as some kind of nat gateway you should consider also using the PREROUTING tables.